# Using arcpy.mapping.ListLayers() with no filter, but some layers are missing in list

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to use `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()` to access and change some of the properties on specific layers in my mxd prior to printing to PDF.  Here is a screen cap of my layer list:

[image]

When troubleshooting, I noticed that 4 of the layers (the ones I've highlighted) are not appearing in the resulting list provided by `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()`.  The layers that are missing are stored in a local gdb; the ones that come through in the list above are stored in SDE.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
mxdpath = os.path.join (sys.path[0],"SectionIDMaps_cover.mxd")
map = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdpath)
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(map)[0]

layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map,"",dataFrame)
```

print result of `layers`:

```
[<map layer u'Recently Closed (past 24 Hours)'>, 
<map layer u'Wards (2012)'>, <map layer u'ANC (2012)'>, 
<map layer u'DC Streets'>, <map layer u'DCGIS.streets'>, 
<map layer u'DC Boundary'>, <map layer u'Buildings'>, 
<map layer u'Water'>, <map layer u'Parks'>, 
<map layer u'DCGIS.ParkPly_Gen'>, <map layer u'DCGIS.DCBndyPly_Gen'>]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I really don't see how this could be going wrong, it's a very simple operation and all the code looks fine.  I would test it with a different map document, and also copy those layers into a new mxd.  And save a new copy of the mxd and try that one.  Also, silly question, but is there any chance that you are looking at a different map document than you think, or that some variables get redefined in your script?  More code here could be helpful.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot using the source tab, that would be more helpful to diagnose why the 4 layers aren't picked up

Answer (score 3):

I think the parameters in `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()` are out of order. As described in the [help documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm), the first parameter is the map document, the **second** parameter is the wildcard, and the **third** parameter is the data frame. You have passed in your `dataFrame` variable as your wildcard, which is why your layers are being filtered. Not sure why you aren't getting zero results, though.

To correct this, you can just remove the `dataFrame` parameter since it's optional:

```
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map)
```

Alternatively, you can correctly specify the data frame parameter:

```
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map, data_frame=dataFrame)
```

As a sidenote, I find it easier to get the active data frame from the `MapDocument` object rather than using `arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames()`, like so:

```
dataFrame = map.activeDataFrame
```

Comment: Drat.  I mis-pasted my example code and have since corrected it.  The ListLayers function works - I still get a list of layers, but the 4 I've highlighted are still not present in the list.